# More than one condition in CASE clause after renaming of column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

| Status | begin_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 2019-12-01 | 2020-09-01 |
| Active | 2019-04-01 | NULL |
| Active | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-09 |
| Inactive | 2019-05-01 | 2020-08-01 |

The result column should contain:

- 'E2' when difference between begin_date and end_date is greater than 14 days or if end_date is NULL
- 'X' when difference between begin_date and end_date is less than or equal to 14 days and
- 'I2' if the status is inactive

I have written this condition out in a CASE statement which takes care of 'E2' and 'X' however it doesn't result in 'I2' when the status is inactive, instead it outputs 'E2'. How do i achieve this result as another condition in the same CASE statement.

Here's the code:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14 THEN 'E2'
    WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 'E2'
    WHEN DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14 
         AND end_date IS NULL AND status = 'Inactive' THEN 'I2'
    ELSE 'X'
END AS Result
```

The output I am getting:

| Status | begin_date | end_date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 2019-12-01 | 2020-09-01 | E2 |
| Active | 2019-04-01 | NULL | E2 |
| Active | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-09 | X |
| Inactive | 2019-05-01 | 2020-08-01 | E2 |

Expected output:

| Status | begin_date | end_date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 2019-12-01 | 2020-09-01 | E2 |
| Active | 2019-04-01 | NULL | E2 |
| Active | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-09 | X |
| Inactive | 2019-05-01 | 2020-08-01 | I2 |

Comment: `DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14  and end_date is NULL` will never be true. If `end_date` is null the `>14` won't be met

Comment: So i should use OR instead of AND? Can i add another CASE statement saying, if result = E2 and status = Inactive then Result should be 'I2'

Comment: TBH - I'd reorder the conditions and have `X` above it and make that the `ELSE`

Comment: Since 'result' is an alias column, will i be able to call it in another case statement before the condition is met?

Comment: If status = 'Inactive' then is all the date checking irrelevant for that row? It should just have a result of I2 irrespective of whatever the dates say? If so this should be the first item in the CASE

Comment: Conditions are searched in the order listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearange your code

and the part where IS NULL and inanctove needs an Or and parenthesis

```
SELECT "Status", "begin_date", "end_date",
CASE
  WHEN (DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14 
      OR end_date is NULL) and status = 'Inactive' THEN 'I2'   
   WHEN DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14 THEN 'E2'
  WHEN end_date is NULL  THEN 'E2'
     
     ELSE 'X'
END AS Result 
FROM testdata
```

| Status | begin_date | end_date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 2019-12-01 | 2020-09-01 | E2 |
| Active | 2019-04-01 | *null* | E2 |
| Active | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-09 | X |
| Inactive | 2019-05-01 | 2020-08-01 | I2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W3vrzncx)

Answer (score 4):

`DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14  and end_date is NULL` will never be true. If `end_date is null` the `>14` won't be met.

I'd reorder your case conditions entirely though.

It seems likely the status is supposed to trump any date logic so this goes first. Then have the simple `<=` condition that will exclude nulls.

The `ELSE` branch will naturally get both cases that `DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) > 14` or `end_date` is null.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN status = 'Inactive' THEN 'I2'
         WHEN DATEDIFF (day, begin_date, end_date) <= 14 THEN 'X'
         ELSE 'E2'
       END AS Result
```

If `begin_date` is null this will also go to the `ELSE` but no logic has been explicitly defined for this (and there is no indication the column is nullable in the example data).